# shcore.dll on Windows 7 -- does it exist?

Tags: c#, windows-7

I am trying to use this function, but I don't have shcore.dll and I can't figure out where to get it.  Is shcore.dll just a Windows 10 DLL?

```
   [DllImport("Shcore.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr GetDpiForMonitor(
            [In] IntPtr hmonitor,
            [In] MonitorDpiType dpiType,
            [Out] out uint dpiX,
            [Out] out uint dpiY);
```

Comment: per Monitor DPI scaling was added starting with 8.1, so no, not available in Win7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not available on Windows 7.
Windows 8.1 or newer is required based on [Microsoft's documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getdpiformonitor)